# "Make folder if not exists" logic fails, but only the first time it runs

Tags: macos, file, applescript, directory, finder

I'm writing a little application in AppleScript, and I want to be able to store some files for it in `~/Library/Application Support/com.example.appname/`. I wrote some logic to check if that folder exists, and create it if it doesn't. (I'm assuming that `~/Library/Application Support/` definitely already exists.) Here's my code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set applicationSupport to (path to library folder from user domain as text) & "Application Support:"
    set configFolderName to "com.example.appname"
    if not (exists folder (applicationSupport & configFolderName & ":")) then
        make new folder at applicationSupport with properties {name:configFolderName}
    end if
    set configFolder to folder (applicationSupport & configFolderName & ":")
end tell
```

The first time you run this, it does **not** create the folder, but it also does not crash on the `make new folder at...` line. Instead, it crashes on the `set configFolder to...` line with the message:

> error "Finder got an error: Can’t get folder \"Macintosh HD:Users:hayden:Library:Application Support:com.example.appname:\"." number -1728 from folder "Macintosh HD:Users:hayden:Library:Application Support:com.example.appname:"

However, the second time you run this, it creates the folder and completes execution without issue, even getting past the line it previously crashed on. If I add `display dialog (configFolder as text)` to the end of the script, it shows:

> Macintosh HD:Users:hayden:Library:Application Support:com.example.appname:

On subsequent runs, it'll also work fine, and show the same message in the dialog.

If I delete the com.example.app directory (with `rm -d`), it resets this -- it'll fail the first time I run it after that (with the same error as above), but then work every subsequent run.

Does anyone have any clue what's causing the first run to fail, what's causing the second run *not* fail, and what I should change to fix it?

If it matters: I'm running this on Mac OS X 10.10.5, using Script Editor.app to test it and saving it as an Application.

Comment: Do not use `.app`, change `set configFolderName to "com.example.app"` to `set configFolderName to "com.example.appname"`, as it should be, and then you'll not have the issue.

Comment: @user3439894 Ah whoops, didn't think of that when picking an example name for Stack Overflow (I've now changed it to "com.example.appname" in the question). My actual identifier is "io.schiff.subtitleedit.maclauncher", so unfortunately that wasn't the issue.

Comment: If I copy and paste the code in your question to Script Editor, it creates the target without throwing a fatal error the first run. It does throw a non-fatal error on the first `set` line.  I'd actually have the first two `set` lines run under `current application` by setting the first two `set` lines before the `tell application "Finder"` block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not really sure what's going on, but I was able to get it working by using POSIX paths (i.e. `/`-delimited) instead of using aliases (i.e. `:`-delimited). Here's my new code:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set applicationSupport to path to application support from user domain
    set configFolderName to "com.example.appname"
    set configFolderPath to (POSIX path of applicationSupport) & configFolderName & "/"
    if not (exists configFolderPath as POSIX file) then
        make new folder at applicationSupport with properties {name:configFolderName}
    end if
    set configFolder to folder configFolderName of applicationSupport
end tell
```

I think the key issue might be that AppleScript really doesn't like you to create a folder/alias/file that refers to something that doesn't exist yet. However, it doesn't seem to mind as much if you have a POSIX file that refers to a non-existent file/folder. The issue might also have something to do with the fact that I'm using the `path to ... from user domain` construct to access my home folder, rather than just hardcoding the path to `/Users/username/...` (this is necessary to ensure the code will run on any machine).

I don't think this is related to the issue, but another thing I changed is that I now get the Application Support folder via `path to application support from user domain` instead of getting `path to library from user domain` and getting the Application Support subfolder.

Comment: If I copy and paste the code in your answer into Script Editor and run it, it errors out, so IMO this is not a valid answer.

Comment: ...I'm finding that happens now too. I swear, I did test it and it was working --something else is afoot. Argh, I'll keep working on it, and update/delete this answer based on what I find.

Comment: @user3439894 I've now updated it to a new solution, and I've retested this one like 5 times so I'm positive it's good! :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be far simpler, IMHO, to just use the `mkdir` command which, when run with the `-p` option, makes all directories needed along the way to get what you want.

So, if you want a directory called `$HOME/Desktop/Some/Long/Path/New`, you would just do:

```
do shell script "mkdir -p $HOME/Desktop/Some/Long/Path/New"
```

Comment: Yeah, that probably would be easier, but I'd really like to learn AppleScript properly and do things "the right way". This is going in an application that I'm distributing to other people, so I'd also be a little bit worried about the potential security implications of passing things through a shell so often.

Answer (score -1):

```
set configFolderName to "com.example.appname"

tell application "System Events"
    if not folder configFolderName of application support folder exists then
        set configFolder to make new folder at application support folder ¬
            with properties {name:configFolderName}
    end if
end tell
```